# Are there old versions of Windows UX guidelines somewhere?

Tags: user-interface, history, user-experience

Since I've read [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) (there's a PDF download avaliable) I've found it to be admirably self-deprecating, humbly pointing out their own horrible UI practices long scolded by [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/).

I'd like to know, however, what they had in mind while they made those mistakes. Is this (terrific) UX Guidelines document something new, or were there previous issues of such? If so, where can I find them? My prayers to Google yielded no leniency.

**EDIT: The bounty will be awarded to anyone who finds an official (Microsoft) UX or UI guideline published before Windows XP.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Microsoft Windows User Experience: Official Guidelines For User Interface Developers And Designers**](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/2466.aspx)

It looks like this book was originally published in September 1999 and covers Windows 98 and Windows 2000.  The first revision was in 2002 and can be found [here](http://www.amazon.ca/Microsoft-Windows-User-Experience-Guidelines/dp/0735605661) on Amazon.  Of course, its not *free*, but it looks like it may be along the lines of what you are looking for.

**Windows Interface Guidelines**

It appears that **Windows Interface Guidelines** was the precursor to the book above and was originally published in 1995.  [Here is](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~kobsa/courses/ICS104/course-notes/Microsoft_WindowsGuidelines.pdf) a PDF version of *Windows Interface Guidelines*

[**New Windows Interface**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556156790)

This book was published in 1994 and intended for Windows 95.  Looks like you could get the book right now via Amazon for $1.50 new or for $0.15 used.

Comment: Amazing answer. You more than deserve the bounty! Will be accepted soon (I can't accept it yet due to website's rules and I may not be here in ~four hours, but I really believe no one would have done better).

Answer (score 4):

Here are two:

Windows User Experience Guidelines for Windows XP and Windows 2000 (2007) @ http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=B996E1E7-A83A-4CAE-936B-2A9D94B11BC5&displayLang=en

Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines (UX Guide) for Windows 7 and Windows Vista (1/2010) @ http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E49820CB-954D-45AE-9CB3-1B9E8EA7FE8C&displayLang=en

Comment: Awesome, but how come the XP and W2K guidelines are from 2007, if development of Windows Vista was already finished in 2006? The second one is the same as what I linked to (But your link is directly to the PDF download)

Comment: Very late, but the first one is actually the "Microsoft Windows User Experience: Official Guidelines For User Interface Developers And Designers" from Zach Johnson's answer above. I'm not sure if it's the 2002 revision or not, though.